# R-Shiny: How to get brush values from a pair plot in shiny using e.g. ggpairs?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a larger application where i need to identify data clusters.
For this I would like to create a pair plot and use the brush option to mark some points. These marked points are later used in another part of the program.

The problem is that i can  not specify the xvar and yvar parameters for the pair plot.
At the moment i have no idea how to solve this.
Is there someone around who had the same problem?

I tried to create a simple application that demonstrates the problem.
Finally i need the IMG_Selected_Tiles variable to mark specific parts of a source image...

Thanks for any help

Jan

```
IMG_SelectedTiles <- reactiveValues ()
IMG_Statistics    <- reactiveValues ()


library ("ggplot2")

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4,
        plotOutput("plot", height=300,
          click = "plot_click",  # Equiv, to click=clickOpts(id="plot_click")
          hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover", delayType = "throttle"),
          brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush")
        ),
        
        h4("Clicked points"),
        tableOutput("plot_clickedpoints"),
        h4("Brushed points"),
        tableOutput("plot_brushedpoints")
      ),
      
      column(width = 4,
        verbatimTextOutput("plot_clickinfo"),
        verbatimTextOutput("plot_hoverinfo")
      ),
      
      column(width = 4,
        wellPanel(actionButton("newplot", "New plot")),
        verbatimTextOutput("plot_brushinfo"),
        verbatimTextOutput("text_IMG_selected_tiles")
      )
    )
  ),
  
  
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
   
    IMG_Statistics$data <- reactive({
      input$newplot
      
      iris
    })
    
       
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      d <- IMG_Statistics$data ()
      ggpairs (d)
      #plot(d$speed, d$dist)
    })
    
    
    output$plot_clickinfo <- renderPrint({
      cat("Click:\n")
      str(input$plot_click)
    })
    
    
    output$plot_hoverinfo <- renderPrint({
      cat("Hover (throttled):\n")
      str(input$plot_hover)
    })
    
    
    output$plot_brushinfo <- renderPrint({
      cat("Brush (debounced):\n")
      str(input$plot_brush)
    })
    
    
    output$plot_clickedpoints <- renderTable({
      # For base graphics, we need to specify columns, though for ggplot2,
      # it's usually not necessary.
      res <- nearPoints(IMG_Statistics$data(), 
                        input$plot_click, 
                        "speed", 
                        "dist")
      
      if (nrow(res) == 0) return()
      
      res
    })
    
    
    output$plot_brushedpoints <- renderTable({
      res <- brushedPoints(IMG_Statistics$data(), input$plot_brush, allRows = TRUE)
      
      if (nrow (res) == 0) return()
      
      #just as an example data are taken from another data structure
      IMG_SelectedTiles <- cbind(IMG_Statistics$data [res_selected_, 1],
                                 IMG_Statistics$data [res_selected_, 2],
                                 IMG_Statistics$data [res_selected_, 3])
    })
    
    
         output$text_IMG_selected_Tiles <-renderTable ({
           cat ("Selected data:\n")
           str (IMG_Selected_Tiles())
    })
    
    
  }
)
```

Comment: Is it `ggpairs` from the **GGally** package?

Comment: Yes it is. But any other pair plot would also be fine. The problem can be extended to other tasks. Throughout the project i have some other generic plots, where i can barely say which variable was chosen...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the help of **plotly**?

```
library(plotly)
library(GGally)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
    highlight_key(iris) %>%
      GGally::ggpairs(aes(color = Species), columns = 1:4) %>%
      ggplotly() %>%
      highlight("plotly_selected") %>%
      layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
      event_register(event = "plotly_brushed") %>%
      event_register(event = "plotly_selected")
  })
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_brushed"), {
    cat("Selected box:\n")
    print(event_data("plotly_brushed"))
    # alternative method 
    #xmin <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$x[1]
    #xmax <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$x[2]
    #ymin <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$y[1]
    #ymax <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$y[2]
  })
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected"), {
    cat("Selected points:\n")
    print(event_data("plotly_selected"))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I never used the brush and selection events of plotly before. Looks good at a first view. But sometimes (after a couple of selections) the event_data("plotly_selected")$key seems to return more points than expected (including reappearing numbers/indices). Not shure, whether i made a mistake or if there is a problem. What is your way to get the indices of rows from the selected points?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, Stéphane!

I finally made a solution for the problem, using your approach in a very similar way.

I think, that this is a little tricky problem. Thus, I prepared some sample code. It is not the most elegant sample, but it may help some others facing a similar problem...

Jan

```
    library ("plotly")

IMG_SelectedTiles   <- reactiveValues ()
IMG_Statistics      <- reactiveValues ()

IMG_selected_keys   <- reactiveValues ()
IMG_selected_points <- reactiveValues ()



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  wellPanel(actionButton("newplot", "New plot")),
   
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  
  h4 ("Selected points"),
  tableOutput("selected_points"),
  
  h4 ("Selected keys"),
  tableOutput("selected_keys"),
  
  h4 ("Selected data"),
  tableOutput("selected_data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
   # get arbitrary data into my reactive variable
   IMG_Statistics$data <- reactive({
      input$newplot
      iris
    })
   
   
  
  output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
      #height = "1500px"
      #width  = "1500px",
  
     highlight_key(IMG_Statistics$data() ) %>%
      
      GGally::ggpairs () %>%#(aes(color = "black"), columns = 1:4) %>%
      
      ggplotly() %>%
      highlight("plotly_selected") %>%
     layout(dragmode = "select", autosize = FALSE, height = 1500, width = 1500) %>%
     # event_register(event = "plotly_brushed") %>%
      event_register(event = "plotly_selected")
    
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_brushed"), {
  #  cat("Selected brush:\n")
  #  print (str (event_data("plotly_brushed")))
    # alternative method 
    #xmin <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$x[1]
    #xmax <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$x[2]
    #ymin <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$y[1]
    #ymax <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$y[2]
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected"), {
  
    cat("Data:\n")
    print (str (IMG_Statistics$data))
    
    IMG_selected_keys$data <- event_data("plotly_selected")$key
    cat("Selected keys:\n")
    print ( IMG_selected_keys$data)
    
    
    IMG_selected_points$data <- event_data("plotly_selected")$pointNumber
    cat("Selected point numbers:\n")
    print (IMG_selected_points$data)
    
    
    
    IMG_SelectedTiles$data <- IMG_Statistics$data () [as.numeric (event_data ("plotly_selected")$key), ] 
    cat("Selected tiles:\n")
    print (IMG_SelectedTiles$data)
  })
  
  
  output$selected_keys <- renderPrint ({IMG_selected_keys$data })
  
  output$selected_points <- renderPrint ({IMG_selected_points$data})
  
  
  output$selected_data <- renderTable({
     IMG_SelectedTiles$data
    
    })
    
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```